# Why create and return an instance of a class within the same class?

Tags: python, database, class, model, static-methods

Noob here.

Actually want to understand the concept behind returning an instance of a class within the class itself. Code snippet below don't actually work, but want to understand idea behind code in the get_student() method (more especially the last two lines).

```
import database
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self, name, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender

    def save(self):
        """Save student data to database"""
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_student(std_id):
        """Retrieve student from database"""
        query = "query" + std_id
        student = database.Database.get_one(query)
        return Student(name=student['name'], gender=student['gender'])
```

Comment: that is a staticmethod, so you call it by doing `<variable_name> = Student.get_student()` not `self` so in this case it is querying the database and returning a `student` with the details it gets from the database

Comment: It's a static method, so you call it using `Student.get_student(id)` instead of `some_student.get_student(id)`. The point of it is to construct a student object from an id. The expression `Student(name=student['name'], gender=['gender']`)` is a call to the student constructor using whatever dictionary or other object `database.Database.get_one(query)` returned. Actually, it should probably be `gender=student['gender']`

Comment: You also need to define `__getitem__` for `student['name']` and `student['gender']` to work.